# How does google set the fullVisitorId/Client ID in Bigquery/Google-Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, session-variables

I have been trying to understand the concept behind google client id, set as fullvisitor id in [BigQuery Export Schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en)

I know that to define a session, a unique combination of fullvisitorid and visitid has to be found.

However,I couldn't find a good explanation regarding how google defines this id, and how permanent it is across sessions.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you didn't understand, but the client id is generated on the user's browser when the GA script is initialised and stored in the cookie.

After that, every hit sent by that instance of the script [that has the cookie] will have the `cid` value as the client id.

When implementing GA you can also set that value yourself if you want. Although there are better ways for doing that.

Here's some documentation on the [cid](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#clientId) and here is how the [session is defined](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en) (thus how the session id is derived during data collection)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, FKrauss. Sometimes I get more than one fullvisitorid for the same visitId. Since this last one is a timestamp, I find it weird that 5 different users would start a session at the same time. So I don't understand why does the fullvisiotorId changes for the same visitid. Maybe this situation is more plausible than I though...

Comment: Do you know how the GA scripts were implemented on the website page? maybe there's some weirdness happening there